# Apply style on text which is having bold

Tags: javascript, css

Like attribute selectors in CSS, is it possible to apply style on text which is in bold inside a DIV. For example I can select a DIV using CSS attribute selector like below

```
 div[attr = value]{
   ...
 }
```

Is there any way to select Bold text like above selector? If JavaScript there are several ways to make that work but I am just looking for possibility of CSS solution. And my target is only Chrome

Comment: Please read specification: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors. Maybe this take a while but simply explain you what browser should support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should be quite easy.

```
div b{font-weight:normal;}
```

this will select every `<b>` tag contained within every `<div>` tag, and set the font weight to normal.

If you wanted to be specific, use the div class or id.

```
#someDivId b{font-weight:normal;}
```

If your bold text is not defined with `<b>` tags, but you know what tags are used, such as span, then you might try,

```
span[style*="font-weight"]{font-weight:normal !important;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/G8NaB/

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 3):

No. CSS doesn't provide any selectors that operate based on the style of an element.

Comment: Unless and until you have nested `b` tag inside an element, than you can use `element b {}`

Comment: @Mr.Alien - That operates on the element type, not the rendering. What if you had `b { font-weight: normal; }` elsewhere in the stylesheet?

Comment: Oh yea, agreed, but even JS can't detect `b` then if we have `b { font-weight: normal;}`

Comment: Yes, it can: `var foo = window.getComputedStyle(document.body, null)['font-weight'];
    if (foo === 'bold') {
      alert("Bold!");      
    };`

Comment: Can also have a condition like `700` right? If this works than that's cool, didn't knew such thing

Comment: Yes, that was a simplified example. You'd need to determine which possible values you consider bold enough for your purposes and check against all of them.

Comment: @Quentin `font-weight` bold would be bold for `b` and `strong` tags too?

Comment: @Exception — Depends on what styles have been applied to them. It's entirely possible to have `b { font-weight: light; }` (although it would almost never make any sense to so do).

Answer (score 1):

According to http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors

> [att*=val] Represents an element with the att attribute whose value
>   contains at least one instance of the substring "val". If "val" is the
>   empty string then the selector does not represent anything.

So you may try:

```
div[style*=bold]{
   ...
 }
```

This will work if you apply inline styles.

Comment: What if the styles are not inline?

Comment: CSS cannot detect whether the class contains font weight bold property :)

Comment: there's no reliable solution! you can make a class which contains font-weight:bold and check for class' presence... or use javascript and don't ask for css solutions

Comment: Exactly, so what he is asking is not possible in CSS :)

Comment: It's also possible for css to specify `700` or `bolder` instead of `bold`, so even a simple inline style wouldn't work reliably. And there are other elements which are bold by default, such as `<b>`, `<th>`, `<h1>` etc., which aren't caught by this...

Answer (score 0):

You can try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/YP6V6/) fiddle.

HTML

```
<div data-role="page">Bold text</div>
```

CSS

```
div[data-role~="page"]{font-weight:bold;}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I would be willing to know the reason for a negative vote. As I tried to resolve the query and probably achieved the same too, so why I deserve a negative vote? If I am not correct, atleast explain me where I am wrong so that I can correct my mistake.